# Using constexpr to initialize objects in std.array

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

I have an array called `foos` with instances of `Foo`. They are stored in an std.array and I would like to initialize them during compile time. Is that possible by using `C++17` and constexpr?

```
struct Foo
{
    constexpr void setA(int a);
    int _a{0};
};

static std::array<Foo, 100> foos;

static constexpr void initialize()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (auto& e : foos)
    {
        e.setA(i++);
    }
}
```

It seems the initialization is still done during runtime. Am I missing something?

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r4WUbE

I am aware that `-O3` will generate better output, but my original example is slightly better and the compiler does not optimize it under this optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constexpr` doesn’t mean “schedule this function to run before (normal) execution begins”.  In particular, a constant expression cannot modify an object (here, any of the `Foo::_a` objects) that it did not create.  You can, however, make a `constexpr` function that *returns* an `array` and use it as an **initializer**:

```
using Foos=std::array<Foo,100>;
constexpr Foos iota_foos() {
  Foos ret;
  int i=0;
  for(auto &f : ret) f.setA(i++);
  return ret;
}

static Foos foos=iota_foos();
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `static constexpr Foos foos=iota_foos();` to enforce that `iota_foos` is evaluated in a constexpr context?

Comment: @JonasGreitemann: There was no statement that `foos` should be `const`.  It’s constant-initialized anyway (but cannot itself be used in constant expressions); C++20 provides `constinit` to *verify* that fact without changing the type.

Comment: Agreed. Upon testing, I checked that gcc and clang constant-initialized it even at `-O0`, but as it stands, there's no way to guarantee this pre-C++20. However, if `foos` were `const`, it really should be `constexpr`. As pointed out by Jason Turner at CppCon, `static const` is a code smell.

Comment: @JonasGreitemann: We can guarantee that `iota_foos` is called at compile time and just have no guaranty about copy constructor: `static constexpr Foos const_foos=iota_foos(); static Foos foos= const_foos();`.

Comment: @JonasGreitemann: Constant initialization isn’t an optimization; it’s just part of the language.  So it is guaranteed, but absent `constexpr`/`constinit` there’s no way to “guarantee the guarantee”.

Comment: @JonasGreitemann: To be more precise, constant initialization *in practice* (as in `.data` or `.rodata` and no `.text`) is an optimization, and one that the language [enables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Early_dynamic_initialization) even when constant initialization *in principle* does not apply.  The ability to use constexpr variables in constant expressions has the unsurprising result that the optimization is reliable in practice because typical compiler architecture necessitates doing the work anyway.